Title: Issues with Fitting a Quasi-Periodic Function with a Trend Term in Python
I'm trying to fit a quasi-periodic function with a trend term to my time series data using Python. The data consists of monthly observations from 1963 to 1976. My goal is to model the data with a function that captures both the periodic components and a linear trend.
Here's the function I'm using for the fit:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Loading the Excel file
file_path = r"C:\Users\xxx\quasi-periodic\HSN1FNSA.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

# Extracting the two time series
observation_date = pd.to_datetime(df['observation_date'])
HSN1FNSA = df['HSN1FNSA']

# Converting dates to numbers (necessary for the fitting function)
x_data = (observation_date - observation_date.min()).dt.days.values
y_data = HSN1FNSA.values

def quasi_periodic_func(x, *params):
    n = (len(params) - 2) // 3
    a = params[:n]
    lambdas = params[n:2*n]
    phases = params[2*n:3*n]
    constant = params[3*n]
    trend = params[3*n + 1]
    result = constant + trend * x
    for i in range(n):
        result += a[i] * np.cos(lambdas[i] * x + phases[i])
    return result

# Number of components to use in the quasi-periodic function
n = 4  # Replace 3 with any desired number of components

# Initial guess for the parameters
# The initial guess needs to have 3 * n elements: n amplitudes, n frequencies, and n phases
initial_guess = [30] * n + [0.1] * n + [0] * n + [50, 0.1]

# Fitting the quasi-periodic function to the data
params_opt, params_covariance = curve_fit(
    quasi_periodic_func, x_data, y_data, p0=initial_guess, maxfev=12000
)

# Print the optimized parameters
print("Optimized parameters:")
for i in range(n):
    print(f"a_{i} = {params_opt[i]}")
    print(f"lambda_{i} = {params_opt[n + i]}")
    print(f"phi_{i} = {params_opt[2*n + i]}")

# Create the fitted data
y_fit = quasi_periodic_func(x_data, *params_opt)

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(observation_date, y_data, label='Observed data', color='blue')
plt.plot(observation_date, y_fit, label='Quasi-periodic fit', color='red')
plt.xlabel('Observation date')
plt.ylabel('HSN1FNSA')
plt.title('Quasi-Periodic Fit of HSN1FNSA Data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

However, when I run this code, the fitted curve is completely off.
Here's the dataset I'm using:
{'observation_date': {0: Timestamp('1963-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('1963-02-01 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('1963-03-01 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('1963-04-01 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('1963-05-01 00:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('1963-06-01 00:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('1963-07-01 00:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('1963-08-01 00:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('1963-09-01 00:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('1963-10-01 00:00:00'), 10: Timestamp('1963-11-01 00:00:00'), 11: Timestamp('1963-12-01 00:00:00'), 12: Timestamp('1964-01-01 00:00:00'), 13: Timestamp('1964-02-01 00:00:00'), 14: Timestamp('1964-03-01 00:00:00'), 15: Timestamp('1964-04-01 00:00:00'), 16: Timestamp('1964-05-01 00:00:00'), 17: Timestamp('1964-06-01 00:00:00'), 18: Timestamp('1964-07-01 00:00:00'), 19: Timestamp('1964-08-01 00:00:00'), 20: Timestamp('1964-09-01 00:00:00'), 21: Timestamp('1964-10-01 00:00:00'), 22: Timestamp('1964-11-01 00:00:00'), 23: Timestamp('1964-12-01 00:00:00'), 24: Timestamp('1965-01-01 00:00:00'), 25: Timestamp('1965-02-01 00:00:00'), 26: Timestamp('1965-03-01 00:00:00'), 27: Timestamp('1965-04-01 00:00:00'), 28: Timestamp('1965-05-01 00:00:00'), 29: Timestamp('1965-06-01 00:00:00'), 30: Timestamp('1965-07-01 00:00:00'), 31: Timestamp('1965-08-01 00:00:00'), 32: Timestamp('1965-09-01 00:00:00'), 33: Timestamp('1965-10-01 00:00:00'), 34: Timestamp('1965-11-01 00:00:00'), 35: Timestamp('1965-12-01 00:00:00'), 36: Timestamp('1966-01-01 00:00:00'), 37: Timestamp('1966-02-01 00:00:00'), 38: Timestamp('1966-03-01 00:00:00'), 39: Timestamp('1966-04-01 00:00:00'), 40: Timestamp('1966-05-01 00:00:00'), 41: Timestamp('1966-06-01 00:00:00'), 42: Timestamp('1966-07-01 00:00:00'), 43: Timestamp('1966-08-01 00:00:00'), 44: Timestamp('1966-09-01 00:00:00'), 45: Timestamp('1966-10-01 00:00:00'), 46: Timestamp('1966-11-01 00:00:00'), 47: Timestamp('1966-12-01 00:00:00'), 48: Timestamp('1967-01-01 00:00:00'), 49: Timestamp('1967-02-01 00:00:00'), 50: Timestamp('1967-03-01 00:00:00'), 51: Timestamp('1967-04-01 00:00:00'), 52: Timestamp('1967-05-01 00:00:00'), 53: Timestamp('1967-06-01 00:00:00'), 54: Timestamp('1967-07-01 00:00:00'), 55: Timestamp('1967-08-01 00:00:00'), 56: Timestamp('1967-09-01 00:00:00'), 57: Timestamp('1967-10-01 00:00:00'), 58: Timestamp('1967-11-01 00:00:00'), 59: Timestamp('1967-12-01 00:00:00'), 60: Timestamp('1968-01-01 00:00:00'), 61: Timestamp('1968-02-01 00:00:00'), 62: Timestamp('1968-03-01 00:00:00'), 63: Timestamp('1968-04-01 00:00:00'), 64: Timestamp('1968-05-01 00:00:00'), 65: Timestamp('1968-06-01 00:00:00'), 66: Timestamp('1968-07-01 00:00:00'), 67: Timestamp('1968-08-01 00:00:00'), 68: Timestamp('1968-09-01 00:00:00'), 69: Timestamp('1968-10-01 00:00:00'), 70: Timestamp('1968-11-01 00:00:00'), 71: Timestamp('1968-12-01 00:00:00'), 72: Timestamp('1969-01-01 00:00:00'), 73: Timestamp('1969-02-01 00:00:00'), 74: Timestamp('1969-03-01 00:00:00'), 75: Timestamp('1969-04-01 00:00:00'), 76: Timestamp('1969-05-01 00:00:00'), 77: Timestamp('1969-06-01 00:00:00'), 78: Timestamp('1969-07-01 00:00:00'), 79: Timestamp('1969-08-01 00:00:00'), 80: Timestamp('1969-09-01 00:00:00'), 81: Timestamp('1969-10-01 00:00:00'), 82: Timestamp('1969-11-01 00:00:00'), 83: Timestamp('1969-12-01 00:00:00'), 84: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00'), 85: Timestamp('1970-02-01 00:00:00'), 86: Timestamp('1970-03-01 00:00:00'), 87: Timestamp('1970-04-01 00:00:00'), 88: Timestamp('1970-05-01 00:00:00'), 89: Timestamp('1970-06-01 00:00:00'), 90: Timestamp('1970-07-01 00:00:00'), 91: Timestamp('1970-08-01 00:00:00'), 92: Timestamp('1970-09-01 00:00:00'), 93: Timestamp('1970-10-01 00:00:00'), 94: Timestamp('1970-11-01 00:00:00'), 95: Timestamp('1970-12-01 00:00:00'), 96: Timestamp('1971-01-01 00:00:00'), 97: Timestamp('1971-02-01 00:00:00'), 98: Timestamp('1971-03-01 00:00:00'), 99: Timestamp('1971-04-01 00:00:00'), 100: Timestamp('1971-05-01 00:00:00'), 101: Timestamp('1971-06-01 00:00:00'), 102: Timestamp('1971-07-01 00:00:00'), 103: Timestamp('1971-08-01 00:00:00'), 104: Timestamp('1971-09-01 00:00:00'), 105: Timestamp('1971-10-01 00:00:00'), 106: Timestamp('1971-11-01 00:00:00'), 107: Timestamp('1971-12-01 00:00:00'), 108: Timestamp('1972-01-01 00:00:00'), 109: Timestamp('1972-02-01 00:00:00'), 110: Timestamp('1972-03-01 00:00:00'), 111: Timestamp('1972-04-01 00:00:00'), 112: Timestamp('1972-05-01 00:00:00'), 113: Timestamp('1972-06-01 00:00:00'), 114: Timestamp('1972-07-01 00:00:00'), 115: Timestamp('1972-08-01 00:00:00'), 116: Timestamp('1972-09-01 00:00:00'), 117: Timestamp('1972-10-01 00:00:00'), 118: Timestamp('1972-11-01 00:00:00'), 119: Timestamp('1972-12-01 00:00:00'), 120: Timestamp('1973-01-01 00:00:00'), 121: Timestamp('1973-02-01 00:00:00'), 122: Timestamp('1973-03-01 00:00:00'), 123: Timestamp('1973-04-01 00:00:00'), 124: Timestamp('1973-05-01 00:00:00'), 125: Timestamp('1973-06-01 00:00:00'), 126: Timestamp('1973-07-01 00:00:00'), 127: Timestamp('1973-08-01 00:00:00'), 128: Timestamp('1973-09-01 00:00:00'), 129: Timestamp('1973-10-01 00:00:00'), 130: Timestamp('1973-11-01 00:00:00'), 131: Timestamp('1973-12-01 00:00:00'), 132: Timestamp('1974-01-01 00:00:00'), 133: Timestamp('1974-02-01 00:00:00'), 134: Timestamp('1974-03-01 00:00:00'), 135: Timestamp('1974-04-01 00:00:00'), 136: Timestamp('1974-05-01 00:00:00'), 137: Timestamp('1974-06-01 00:00:00'), 138: Timestamp('1974-07-01 00:00:00'), 139: Timestamp('1974-08-01 00:00:00'), 140: Timestamp('1974-09-01 00:00:00'), 141: Timestamp('1974-10-01 00:00:00'), 142: Timestamp('1974-11-01 00:00:00'), 143: Timestamp('1974-12-01 00:00:00'), 144: Timestamp('1975-01-01 00:00:00'), 145: Timestamp('1975-02-01 00:00:00'), 146: Timestamp('1975-03-01 00:00:00'), 147: Timestamp('1975-04-01 00:00:00'), 148: Timestamp('1975-05-01 00:00:00'), 149: Timestamp('1975-06-01 00:00:00'), 150: Timestamp('1975-07-01 00:00:00'), 151: Timestamp('1975-08-01 00:00:00'), 152: Timestamp('1975-09-01 00:00:00'), 153: Timestamp('1975-10-01 00:00:00'), 154: Timestamp('1975-11-01 00:00:00'), 155: Timestamp('1975-12-01 00:00:00'), 156: Timestamp('1976-01-01 00:00:00'), 157: Timestamp('1976-02-01 00:00:00'), 158: Timestamp('1976-03-01 00:00:00'), 159: Timestamp('1976-04-01 00:00:00'), 160: Timestamp('1976-05-01 00:00:00'), 161: Timestamp('1976-06-01 00:00:00'), 162: Timestamp('1976-07-01 00:00:00'), 163: Timestamp('1976-08-01 00:00:00'), 164: Timestamp('1976-09-01 00:00:00'), 165: Timestamp('1976-10-01 00:00:00'), 166: Timestamp('1976-11-01 00:00:00'), 167: Timestamp('1976-12-01 00:00:00')}, 'HSN1FNSA': {0: 42, 1: 35, 2: 44, 3: 52, 4: 58, 5: 48, 6: 62, 7: 56, 8: 49, 9: 44, 10: 39, 11: 31, 12: 39, 13: 46, 14: 53, 15: 49, 16: 52, 17: 53, 18: 54, 19: 56, 20: 48, 21: 45, 22: 37, 23: 33, 24: 38, 25: 44, 26: 53, 27: 49, 28: 54, 29: 57, 30: 51, 31: 58, 32: 48, 33: 44, 34: 42, 35: 37, 36: 42, 37: 43, 38: 53, 39: 49, 40: 49, 41: 40, 42: 40, 43: 36, 44: 29, 45: 31, 46: 26, 47: 23, 48: 29, 49: 32, 50: 41, 51: 44, 52: 49, 53: 47, 54: 46, 55: 47, 56: 43, 57: 45, 58: 34, 59: 31, 60: 35, 61: 43, 62: 46, 63: 46, 64: 43, 65: 41, 66: 44, 67: 47, 68: 41, 69: 40, 70: 32, 71: 32, 72: 34, 73: 40, 74: 43, 75: 42, 76: 43, 77: 44, 78: 39, 79: 40, 80: 33, 81: 32, 82: 31, 83: 28, 84: 34, 85: 29, 86: 36, 87: 42, 88: 43, 89: 44, 90: 44, 91: 48, 92: 45, 93: 44, 94: 40, 95: 37, 96: 45, 97: 49, 98: 62, 99: 62, 100: 58, 101: 59, 102: 64, 103: 62, 104: 50, 105: 52, 106: 50, 107: 44, 108: 51, 109: 56, 110: 60, 111: 65, 112: 64, 113: 63, 114: 63, 115: 72, 116: 61, 117: 65, 118: 51, 119: 47, 120: 55, 121: 60, 122: 68, 123: 63, 124: 65, 125: 61, 126: 54, 127: 52, 128: 46, 129: 42, 130: 37, 131: 30, 132: 37, 133: 44, 134: 55, 135: 53, 136: 58, 137: 50, 138: 48, 139: 45, 140: 41, 141: 34, 142: 30, 143: 24, 144: 29, 145: 34, 146: 44, 147: 54, 148: 57, 149: 51, 150: 51, 151: 53, 152: 46, 153: 46, 154: 46, 155: 39, 156: 41, 157: 53, 158: 55, 159: 62, 160: 55, 161: 56, 162: 57, 163: 59, 164: 58, 165: 55, 166: 49, 167: 47}}

And here's what the fitted curve looks like:

I'm wondering if there's something wrong with the initial guesses for the parameters or with the way the function is defined. I've tried adjusting the initial guesses, but I keep getting a poor fit.
Any suggestions on how to improve the fit would be greatly appreciated!

Since I don't have your data I cannot reproduce the numerical calculus and see what went wrong.
Nevertheless a rough checking was carried out from approximative data obtained by scanning the graph given in the question. Of course this is not recomended.
The result is shown below using an available software (with MathCad). The symbols are not the same as the symbols used in the question but it is easy to understand the relationship.

The red curve represents the fited function i.e. sum of linear function and only one sinusidal function. In is important that a parameter phi be included. Or alternatively a function sin AND a function cos.
Of course the red curve only shows the main trend. The large fluctuations around the main trend doesn't appear. More sinusidal terms with higher frequency should be necessary to add into the equation. But the fitting with many sinusoidal terms becomes very arduous and unreliable.
NOTE : For non-linear regression Python (or similar tools) proceed with iterative calculus starting from "guessed" initial values of the parameters. Trouble may comes if the initial values are too far from the unknown correct values. In order to avoid the difficulty a non conventional method of fitting which doesn't requires initial "guessed" values was used for the above fitting : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales
pages 47-53.
